# JPA Query.getResultList( with empty result list

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

All the questions reguards this argument says that if the query has no results the Hibernate framework returns null (if is an older version) or an empty list (if is a newer version). 
In my case I am executing the following piece of code:

```
   22 public boolean aggiungiUtente(String nomeOperatore, String password, String idSuperUser){

   23 KinOperatoreEntity nuovo = new KinOperatoreEntity();
   24 int ultimo = prendiMaxIdUser();

   27 ultimo++;
   28 nuovo.setIdOperatore(ultimo);
   29 nuovo.setPassword(password);
   30 nuovo.setUsername(nomeOperatore);
   31 nuovo.setCodiceAttivita(idSuperUser);
   32 em.persist(nuovo);
   33 return true;
}

    36 private int prendiMaxIdUser() {
   37 String query = "SELECT max(k.idOperatore) from KinOperatoreEntity k";
   38 Query q = em.createQuery(query);
   39 List<Integer> lista= q.getResultList();

   41 if(lista == null) return -1;
   42 if(lista.isEmpty()) return -1;

   44 int result = lista.get(0);

   46 return result;
}
```

The program throws a nullpointer exception because of the line lista.get(0). Why ?????
Could be that the problem is in the query ?

```
                   18:03:44,504 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-4) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component UtentiEjb for method public boolean javaEjbs.UtentiEjb.aggiungiUtente(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:159)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:256)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:329)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
at javaEjbs.UtentiEjb$$$view17.aggiungiUtente(Unknown Source)
at serviziRest.RestUser.aggiungiUtente(RestUser.java:27)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
at serviziRest.RestUser$$$view4.aggiungiUtente(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:402)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)




      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javaEjbs.UtentiEjb.prendiMaxIdUser(UtentiEjb.java:46)
at javaEjbs.UtentiEjb.aggiungiUtente(UtentiEjb.java:25)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:254)
... 152 more
```

EDIT with Integer

```
    22 public boolean aggiungiUtente(String nomeOperatore, String password, String idSuperUser){

   24 KinOperatoreEntity nuovo = new KinOperatoreEntity();
   25 int ultimo = prendiMaxIdUser();

   27 ultimo++;
   28 nuovo.setIdOperatore(ultimo);
   29 nuovo.setPassword(password);
   30 nuovo.setUsername(nomeOperatore);
   31 nuovo.setCodiceAttivita(idSuperUser);
   32 em.persist(nuovo);
   33 return true;
}

36 private int prendiMaxIdUser() {
   37 String query = "SELECT max(k.idOperatore) from KinOperatoreEntity k";
   38 Query q = em.createQuery(query);
   39 List<Integer> lista= q.getResultList();

   41 if(lista == null) return -1;
   42 if(lista.isEmpty()) return -1;

   44 Integer result = lista.get(0);

   46 return result;
}


    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javaEjbs.UtentiEjb.prendiMaxIdUser(UtentiEjb.java:46)
at javaEjbs.UtentiEjb.aggiungiUtente(UtentiEjb.java:25)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:254)
... 152 more
```

Cannot edit with all the second stack trace, the first part (referred to ejb is the same of the previous stack trace.

Comment: `lista.get(0)` returns `null` which is a valid `Integer` but cannot be assigned to a simply `int` and will cause your NPE. But with the given information no one can tell you why your query returns that.

Comment: As OH GOD SPIDERS pointed change first `int` to `Integer`. Then you might notice you have just one `null` value in list. Maybe if you share the whole stack trace it reveals something more but check the quuery / data.

Comment: The fact is that the NPE is referred to the fact that the object lista is null (so, when I call lista.get() it cannot call the method because of null object). But I check if lista is null just 2 commands before !
What informations do you need ? 
I can give you all

Comment: Tried to change int in Integer but is the same thing 
i am editing with stack trace

Comment: Check & add yet the line numbers to your code snippet, it might help. And change it to `Integer result` in snippet also. Does NPE appear at the same line regardless if `int` or  `Integer`?

Comment: Yes, the problem appears in the same line if i set Integer or int. Editing with lines

Comment: `46 return result;` -> `25 int ultimo = prendiMaxIdUser();`  Not Integer here either. Log the result of lista.get(0). Seems not to be ther problem but again trying to put it into `int`.

Comment: ok 
there was a logic problem. query.getresultlist() returns a list with a null value (size = 1, list.get(0) = null). 
I added  if(lista.get(0) == null) return 0; (so is perfect in my case). 
The only thing that i don't understand is why q.getresultlist() returns this kind of result in case of empty database

Comment: Yes as was told in the 1st & 2nd comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no row in the table corresponding to entity `KinOperatoreEntity`
or in all rows, the column corresponding to the field `idOperatore` is `NULL`
then the query will return a `List<Integer>` with a single `NULL` item.

When you try to return it from the method at `line 46`, as the method's
return type is `int`, it tries to unbox the variable, converting an `Integer` to `int`. But as the `result` variable contains a `null` value, you get `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Yes 
you got the problem. Thank you the same for understanding my problem 
Solved it adding if(lista.get(0) == null) return 0;